# Can I specify a specific branch on GitHub pull-only (read-only)?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to set a specific branch on GitHub to pull-only (read-only) or can I only set this for the whole repository?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to disallow pushing on specific branches?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097437/6309

Comment: You can do this easily with bitbucket.

Comment: Note: this is now (Sept. 2015) possible with GitHub! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32384255/6309).

Comment: Note: since March 2016, an organization can restrict push to certain team members. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32384255/6309)

Comment: It's now (Oct 20th, 2022) supported officially. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74343915/1592410

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do branch level permissions on Github, but [the gitolite project](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) supports what you're looking for.

Comment: well it's possible, but I can't speak to the roadmap of features Github intends to deploy. It's technically possible, but I don't know if Github intends to ever support it

Comment: since I posted this several years ago, @VonC's looks like it works for Github. Gitlab also supports protected branches.

Comment: Add the branch as a protected branch and then there is an option as : Lock Branch (Branch is read-only. Users cannot push to the branch.)

Answer (score 17):

You actually can (sort of), since September 2015.

That is because you now have "[Protected branches and required status checks](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks)" (September 3, 2015), which allows you to protect a branch:

- against forced pushed
- against deletion
- against merged changes until required status checks pass

As mentioned [in the twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/github/status/639482282240253952):

> > @github nice, what about protect from just push and allow only operating through pull requests?
>
> Adam Roben ‏@aroben @lowl4tency **You can do this via the Status API:
>
>   create a "`success`" status only on commits in PRs, then mark that status as required**.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/25792/9596474/27db3ce6-502a-11e5-9b19-5b47a8addc65.png]

---

[Since Nov. 2015](https://plus.google.com/), you can protect a branch with the API:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/github/hubot/branches/master" \
  -XPATCH \
  -H 'Authorization: token TOKEN'
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.loki-preview" \
  -d '{
    "protection": {
      "enabled": true,
      "required_status_checks": {
        "enforcement_level": "everyone",
        "contexts": [
          "required-status"
        ]
      }
    }
  }'
```

> How can I try it?
>
> To access this functionality during the preview period, you’ll need to provide the following custom media type in the Accept header:

```
application/vnd.github.loki-preview+json
```

---

[Since March 2016](https://github.com/blog/2137-protected-branches-improvements), **Organizations can now specify which members and teams are able to push to a protected branch**.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4719/14140705/ed98abac-f67a-11e5-951e-b48c842fb77f.png]

Answer (score 2):

This request can now be done with the option **Lock branch**.

Reference: [New Branch Protections: Last Pusher and Locked Branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-new-branch-protections-last-pusher-and-locked-branch/)

> ### Lock branch
>
> This allows for branches to be locked, prohibiting changes. You can lock a branch allowing you to have a maintenance window and prevent changes, or to protect a fork so it only receives changes from its upstream repository.
>
> To use this feature in a branch protection rule, enable Lock branch.
>
> [image: Screenshot of Lock branch with fork sync enabled]

Comment: This is the correct modern answer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from March 30th 2016, GitHub does support branch permissions without any further tricks like required status checks: https://github.com/blog/2137-protected-branches-improvements

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Settings, Add the branch as a protected branch and then there is an option as : Lock Branch (Branch is read-only. Users cannot push to the branch.)