# github - enable branch lock

Tags: github, github-api

As a GitHub administrator, I would like to lock a particular branch in GitHub for all users.
For e.g. if I do not want anyone to push to Master/Production or a Project branch, how can I do that.

Instead of using any client side hooks, is there a way to lock a branch on GitHub server directly ? Are there any third party tools/api's/scripts which can help achieve this ?

Comment: As of September 2015, you can now protect branches directly in Github: https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks

Comment: As of Oct. 2022, you actually have a ["lock" option on branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74143308/6309).

Answer (score 12):

@Saurabh, I have done a similar thing according to your requirement on GitHub:

- Navigate to **Settings**
- Navigate to **Branches**
- Tap on **Add Rule** near "Branch protection rules"
- Tick the **Require pull request reviews before merging** checkbox

These steps apply a lock on, for example to `master`, so that no collaborators can push code to this branch. Code only be merged using pull requests.

[Link to documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-branch-restrictions)

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note: Protected branches are available to Pro, Team, and Enterprise users**

[image: note pro feature only]

Answer (score 6):

Since Oct. 2022, there is a simpler option:

> ### [New Branch Protections: Last Pusher and Locked Branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-new-branch-protections-last-pusher-and-locked-branch) (Oct. 2022)
>
> #### Push protection enabled.
>
> This allows for branches to be locked, prohibiting changes.
> You can lock a branch allowing you to have a maintenance window and prevent changes, or to protect a fork so it only receives changes from its upstream repository.
>
> To use this feature in a branch protection rule, enable **Lock branch**.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/196246562-59b7b156-a180-4830-ae67-d202ec49f172.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of Lock branch with fork sync enabled]
>
> For more information, read [About protected branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#about-branch-protection-settings) in the GitHub documentation.
>
> We appreciate feedback on this and other topics in GitHub's [public feedback discussions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/repositories).

Comment: Does this still allow approved PRs to be merged?

Comment: @Marko Good question, I have not tested it. The [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#lock-branch) states: "Locking a branch ensures that no commits can be made to the branch.". So I would say: "no".

Comment: I tested this today. It is not possible to merge a PR into a locked branch.

Comment: @Jagerber48 OK, that makes sense, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to have that branch in its own repo (for which no collaborators) are declared.

Otherwise, GitHub doesn't provide any native "branch protection" feature, as mentioned in "[How to protect “master” in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10381672/6309)"

You *could* setup [a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) which on a [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) can refuse the push if the branch has a given name.

An example would be [`terite/pull-to-master`](https://github.com/terite/pull-to-master) which protects `master`:

```js
if (json.ref != 'refs/heads/master')
  return cb([200, 'Skipping, not master']);
```

This is not a client-side hook, but it does require a client to listen to the JSON payload of the push event in order to react to it.