# Github collaborations - security around main repo

Tags: git, security, github, collaboration

I've recently given collaborator access to a private github repo to a few new team members. While I do trust them, I'd like to better understand their `read/write` access. Couldn't they technically commit directly to `dev` or `master`, accept their own merge requests, or even like remove the entire project? How do I configure security settings so they can only push changes to `dev`/`master`, and I'm the only one who can merge them in?

According to https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/, it seems that a collaborator is free to do what they want.

Comment: https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to give access to a [fork of the private repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) (the fork remains private)

That way:

- they can make pull request to your main repo, with you deciding to merge them or not.
- they can use any branch they want on the fork.

The other approach would be to use the [GitHub new protected branch feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383909/6309): that can limit what a collaborator can do when merging to `master`.