# PyCharm/Git Locking branch (read only) doesn't work after switching to another

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to avoid accidentally editing `master` branch in my project. `PyCharm` has a great feature to "lock" the branch.

[image]

The problem is that it's almost useless because it locks the branch only until switching to another. If I checkout another branch and then go back to master, it's unlocked.

Is it possible to do this permanently or some alternative using pure `GIT`?

Comment: Option you mentioned doesn't lock branch - it sets read-only status on currently opened file. You could find some suggestions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471340/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-branch-in-git

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks!